# Stale Pathauto Alias

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I'm just curious how other Drupal developers handle nested path aliases when they are based on another page's url pattern.

I have a product landing page (it's a "basic page" node). When it's created, right now, the url is:

`/product`

For my product nodes, I set up a path alias to be

`/product/[node:title]`

This makes my product detail pages nicely nested under "product." This works fine for a while. But later, if someone changes the product landing page url, the alias for the product nodes will not match.

Say someone edits the product landing url to be:

`/widgets`

Then I have a `/widgets` landing page and a bunch of product nodes with urls like `/product/product-name`.

Is there a nice way to handle this? Or is it up to content creators to just know they need to update it?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) if you aren't already.

This has a feature (tab) that lets you bulk update the content type urls to `/widgets/[node:title]`.

You should also install the [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module, so that all your former `/products/[node:title]` automatically redirect to `/widgets/[node:title]`. This is for SEO purposes, you don't want your Google listing pointing to a broken link, non-existent page.

Comment: Thank you. I am using Pathauto. I guess there's no better way. I just have to hope that the site admins we train remember to run the bulk update. 

I was just hoping there might be some way of automating that. I wish I could have an alias like /[node:21:title]/[node:title]. But I know it doesn't work that way.

Comment: You could if you create your own token